# Call method for different UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I am making master detail application, i have dynamic Detail ViewController. Detail ViewController are changed.

But in every Detail ViewController I have one common method `updateInfo` I want to call that method

Here is my code

```
UINavigationController *nav=[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
 UIViewController *controller=[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
 [controller updateLastInfo];
```

But it gives me error no method found.

it will work if i use UIViewController name.

```
  HomeViewController *controller=(HomeViewController)[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
     [controller updateLastInfo];
```

**But i dnt want to do above things**.

I have tried to explain. Please  help

Comment: If you want a very unsafe way you could make your controller object of type `id` instead of `UIViewController`. That is the fastest way, but certainly not safe.

Comment: why not do the above thing while that's the correct way?

Comment: Because that id could be any object, and not every object has that method. It relies on your personal knowledge of the code.

Comment: @pasta12 thanks using id it not showing a error

Comment: @pasta12 i understood but in my case all the id will have a method

Comment: It will definitely work, just my opinion that it's not good programming practice.

Comment: then in my case what to do best. because I want to do like this whenever the app terminate i want to save info. i have more than 10 ViewController. i dnot want to make Switch and if else condition. or isKindOfclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `id`

```
 UINavigationController *nav=[self.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    id controller=[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [controller updateLastInfo];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could subclass `UIViewController` and make a base `DetailViewController` class that houses common functionality of your detail view controllers. Then you would make all of your detail view controllers subclass `DetailViewController` instead of `UIViewController`. This would be a safe way to do it and would also allow you to add extra functionality to your `updateInfo` method in the specific detail view controllers.

---

If you want an unsafe way, you could make your controller object of type `id`. I wouldn't suggest this approach as it relies on your personal knowledge of the code. If someone else (or yourself down the road) sets it to a view controller that doesn't have that method, the code will still try to run and will crash.

Answer (score 1):

`UIViewController` doesn't have a method named `updateInfo`, so the compiler will of course complain when you try to send that message to a pointer that's known only to point to an instance of `UIViewController`. When you use the class name, like this:

```
HomeViewController *controller=(HomeViewController)[nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
```

you're providing more information to the compiler, using a type cast to tell it "Hey, don't worry, I know for certain that the object I'll get back is a `HomeViewController`. Since you seem to have several types of view controllers that all have this method, the best thing to do is to declare the `updateInfo` method in a protocol and then have each of those `UIViewController` subclasses implement that protocol. So, your protocol declaration would be in a header file and might look like:

```
@protocol SomeProtocol

- (void)updateInfo

@end
```

and each class that has an `-updateInfo` method would just need to declare that it adopts the protocol:

```
@interface HomeViewController <SomeProtocol>
//...
@end
```

and then make sure that you have an `-updateInfo` in your class implementation:

```
@implementation HomeViewController

- (void)updateInfo {
    //...
}

//...
@end
```

Then, in your code, you can either check that the object conforms to the protocol using `-conformsToProtocol:` like this:

```
if ([controller conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SomeProtocol)]) {
    UIViewController<SomeProtocol> *c = (UIViewController<SomeProtocol>*)controller;
    [c updateInfo];
}
```

or else just check that the object responds to the selector before calling it:

```
if ([controller respondsToSelector:@selector(updateInfo)]) {
    [controller performSelector(updateInfo)];
}
```

The other answers you've received (using `id` or creating a common base class) are also good ones, but to be safe make sure you do some checking before calling your method. For example, you can use `-isKindOfClass` to make sure that the view controller you get back is in fact an instance of your common base class, and you can use `-respondsToSelector:` as above to check that an `id` points to an object that implements `updateInfo`.

Comment: Where i need to make this protocal "SomeProtocolName". in all UIViewContrller?

Comment: You *declare* the protocol once, usually in a header file. Then you *adopt* the protocol in each class that needs it. Read up on protocols in Apple's [documentation on the subject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html). I'll add a little more above as well.

Comment: @Caleb This is another good, safe solution. The only problem I see is that he /she would have to duplicate the same code in all of the detail view controllers. It sounds like they want the detail view controllers to all use the same implementation of the `updateInfo` method, which is better suited as a base class so changing one method doesn't force you to have to change the method in all of the other classes, and you can still easily add a more specific implementation in the subclasses if needed. Just my two cents. Trying not to be biased since I left the base class answer :)

Comment: I guess it really depends on how different the `updateInfo` methods will be. Protocol is well suited for different, base class is well suited for similar.

Comment: @pasta12 No argument there -- perhaps I read too much into the question, but I took the OP to mean that there are a number of different "detail" view controller classes, each with its own `-updateInfo` method.

Comment: @Caleb It's definitely possible. Hard to say what the optimal solution is without being in the code.